# Push elements to array does not work in type script

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have implement table using `MatTableModule` in angular using `typescripts`.

It is working fine when I assign value to `datasource` like this,

```
let dataRow = {name: dealerInfo.name, address: dealerInfo.address, town: dealerInfo.town, contact:dealerInfo.contact};
this.dataSource = [dataRow];
```

As I need to add rows dynamically I used push() as follows (but it doesn't work, it does not show data in the html),

```
let dataRow = {name: dealerInfo.name, address: dealerInfo.address, town: dealerInfo.town, contact:dealerInfo.contact};
this.dataSource.push(dataRow);
```

This is how my data source defined.

```
dataSource: any [] = [];
```

What should be the correct way of adding elements dynamically?

Comment: This is like saying "push elements to array does not work in Javascript". There's no such thing as Typescript as far as the browser is concerned. Can you recreate your problem in a Stackblitz?

Comment: Does `this.dataSource = [...this.dataSource, dataRow];` work? In that case it's Angular's change detector that doesn't pick up the call to `push`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to create a MatTableDatasource is to create an instance of it that you pass as `[dataSource]` property

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any> = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
```

You can pass initial data in the constructor. Then you push to its `data` property

```
this.dataSource.data.push(dealerInfo);
```

Since you are copying properties 1:1 by name, there's no need to create intermediate objects first.

Also, create an interface instead of using `any`

```
export interface TableRow {
    name: string;
    ...
}
```

and

```
new MatTableDataSource<TableRow>();
```

[Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#datasource):

> **DataSource**
>
> For most real-world applications, providing the table a DataSource
>   instance will be the best way to manage data. The DataSource is meant
>   to serve a place to encapsulate any sorting, filtering, pagination,
>   and data retrieval logic specific to the application.

Comment: this.dataSource.data.push(dealerInfo); did not work. Instead I have defined another array of TableRow type and collect all the rows to it. Finally assign it to this.dataSource.data and it works.

Comment: That's not how it should be done. Very ineffective. @abo

Answer (score 0):

With the support of @baao's answer I solved the issue as follows,

```
  // Defined variables.
  rowDataArr: RowData[] = [];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<RowData> = new MatTableDataSource<RowData>();
```

And once I received data from back end.

```
valuesFromBackEnd.forEach(rowData=> {
          this.rowDataArr.push(rowData);
        });
        this.dataSource.data = this.rowDataArr;
```